# Create one variable out of multiple others in R, but one outcome isn't recognized as a factor?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create one variable out of multiple others. So I first created factor variables for each of the different variables as shown below:

> usl <- mutate(usl,
> unsafenat1_fct = case_when(unsafenat1 == 0 ~ "Not mentioned",
> unsafenat1 == 1 ~ "Yes mentioned"),
> unsafenat1_fct = as.factor(unsafenat1_fct))
>
> usl <- mutate(usl,
> unsafenat2_fct = case_when(unsafenat2 == 0 ~ "Not mentioned",
> unsafenat2 == 1 ~ "Yes mentioned"),
> unsafenat2_fct = as.factor(unsafenat2_fct))

And then out of these (and multiple others) I want to create a variable as shown below:

> usl <- mutate(usl, unsafenat = ifelse(unsafenat1_fct == "Yes
> mentioned" | unsafenat2_fct == "Yes mentioned" |
> unsafenat3_fct == "Yes mentioned" | unsafenat4_fct == "Yes mentioned" |
> unsafenat5_fct == "Yes mentioned" | unsafenat6_fct == "Yes mentioned" |
> unsafenat7_fct == "Yes mentioned" | unsafenat8_fct == "Yes mentioned" |
> unsafenat9_fct == "Yes mentioned" | unsafenat10_fct == "Yes mentioned" |
> unsafenat11_fct == "Yes mentioned" | unsafenat12_fct == "Yes mentioned"|
> unsafenat97_fct == "Yes mentioned", "Yes mentioned", "Not mentioned"),
> unsafenat = as.factor(unsafenat))

Basically I want that if the outcome in any of the initial variables was "Yes mentioned" then I want the outcome in my new variable to also be "Yes mentioned" but if it isn't "Yes mentioned" in none of them then I want it to be "Not mentioned". However, when I do this code it only recognizes the "Yes mentioned" and all the others are added to the NA group and I don't know why.

Here's a look at the variables:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIhOJ.png)

When I tried a different coding, it become clear that the problem is that it doesn't recognize "Not mentioned" as a factor but I don't understand why.

> usl$unsafeethn[usl$unsafeethn1_fct == "Not mentioned"]<-"Not
> mentioned"
>
> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, usl$unsafeethnn1_fct == "Not
> mentioned",  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Please can you post a reproducible example with sample data (e.g., by using `dput(your_data_frame)`.

Comment: The likely issue is that factors have levels and labels, which are not fully specified when you create them. It may be useful to specify the different labels upfront when you define the variables as factors so that the other labels get recognized later.

Comment: Obviously, you could also avoid using factors alltogether.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I don't know how to use dput. When I check for levels, both seems to be specified though as it recognizes "Not mentioned" and "Yes mentioned" so I'm not sure what to do about it. How could I do this without using factors then?

Comment: You use `dput` by entering `dput(usl)` into your console and add the output to your post.

Comment: Look here for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create different `_fct` variables for each column. If you have 1/0 values in the `'unsafenat'` column you can sum them and assign `"Yes mentioned"` only when there is at least one 1 in the row.

```
library(dplyr)

usl <- usl %>%
  mutate(unsafenat = ifelse(rowSums(select(., starts_with('unsafenat')), 
                            na.rm = TRUE) > 0, "Yes mentioned", "Not mentioned"))
```